# Why Is my rendered image a white silhouette?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

a newbie of blender is here to ask some help with his own stuff, i searched online tutorials and used a blender manual to make simple stuff for learning. I wanted to make an Espresso cup but it turns out like this:[image]

I'll post my blender file too: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kI9nIBejeWbxEpaqrXZZINGjX4gNpdhF/view?usp=sharing

i'm sorry for bothering but i wanna learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your compositing nodes :

[image: demo pic]

Basically, your nodes are doing the following :

Take the rendered image, blur it, 100% mix with white and done.

I'm not sure of what you tried to do, may just remove the mix node and blur node.

Comment: Yeah it was that. What i was trying to do? I copied a you tube video how to make cermaic looking material and he said to insert this stuff but in his model was more let's say normal? Thanks

Comment: If this answers your question, don't forget to accept it through the green mark on the top left corner.